# Using UNION clause in OPENQUERY to query Oracle Linked Server with VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, oracle, vba, linked-server

I am considerably new to SQL and VBA. I am trying to execute the following Oracle SQL query using OPENQUERY in VBA to query a Linked Server:

```
with 
untagged_affiliates as (
  select 
    ife.entityid,
    'Untagged affiliate' as TYPE_CHANGE,
    to_number(
      case when IFE.OLDVALUE is not null 
        then EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(IFE.OLDVALUE), '/DocumentElement/ORG_AFFILIATIONS/AFFILIATED_ORGID')
        else null
      end) as RELATED_ID,
    ife.analystuserid as ANALYST,
    ife.auditdatetime

    from ife.audittrail ife
    where
      IFE.ATTRIBUTEID = 314
      and 
      ife.newvalue is null
      and 
      ife.oldvalue is not null
      and
      ife.AUDITDATETIME
      between 
      TO_DATE('27/11/2016 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
      and 
      TO_DATE('03/12/2016 23:59:59 ','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
),
untagged_unv_subs as (
  select 
    to_number(ife.oldvalue) as EntityID,
    'Untagged Unverified Sub' as TYPE_CHANGE,
    ife.entityid as RELATED_ID,
    ife.analystuserid as ANALYST,
    ife.auditdatetime

    from ife.audittrail ife
    left join oa.organizations o on ife.entityid = o.orgid

    where
      IFE.ATTRIBUTEID = 268
      and 
      ife.newvalue is null
      and 
      ife.oldvalue is not null
      and
      o.org_is_verified = 0
      and
      o.org_immediate_parent_orgid is null
      and
      ife.AUDITDATETIME
      between 
       TO_DATE('27/11/2016 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
      and 
      TO_DATE('03/12/2016 23:59:59 ','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
),
union_queries as
(
  select * from untagged_affiliates
  union
  select * from untagged_unv_subs
)
select 
  uq.*,
  case
      when (L.LOCATION_NAME = 'Bangalore') then 'BLR'
      when (L.LOCATION_NAME = 'Beijing' or L.LOCATION_NAME = 'Singapore') then 'Asia'
      when (L.LOCATION_NAME = 'Gdansk' or L.LOCATION_NAME = 'Nicosia') then 'EMEA'
      else 'Other'
    end as REGION,
    C.COUNTRYDESC,
    u.USERID,
    u.username as ANALYST
  from union_queries uq
  left join oa.organizations o on uq.entityid = o.orgid
  left join admin.USERS U on UQ.ANALYST = U.USERID
  inner join admin.USERSUSERGROUPS ug on u.userid = ug.userid and ug.groupcode in (1,2,4,29,30,31,34,42,43,45,46,55,56)
  left join DOMAINS.COUNTRYCODES C on coalesce(o.org_country_of_domicile,o.org_country_of_incorporation) = C.COUNTRYCODE
  left join domains.TR_LOCATIONS l on u.PRIMARYLOCATION = l.LOCATION_ID
```

The corresponding VBA code I'm using to query the Linked Server is the following:

```
'SQL_String = "select * from openquery([OA],'with " & _
'"untagged_affiliates as (select ife.entityid, to_number( case when IFE.OLDVALUE is not null then EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(IFE.OLDVALUE), ''/DocumentElement/ORG_AFFILIATIONS/AFFILIATED_ORGID'') else null end) as RELATED_ID, ife.analystuserid as ANALYST, ife.auditdatetime from ife.audittrail ife where IFE.ATTRIBUTEID = 314 and ife.newvalue is null and ife.oldvalue is not null and ife.AUDITDATETIME between TO_DATE(''" & from_date_string & " 00:00:00'',''dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') and TO_DATE(''" & to_date_string & " 23:59:59 '',''dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') ), " & _
'"untagged_unv_subs as (select to_number(ife.oldvalue) as EntityID, ife.entityid as RELATED_ID, ife.analystuserid as ANALYST, ife.auditdatetime from ife.audittrail ife left join oa.organizations o on ife.entityid = o.orgid where IFE.ATTRIBUTEID = 268 and ife.newvalue is null and ife.oldvalue is not null and o.org_is_verified = 0 and o.org_immediate_parent_orgid is null and ife.AUDITDATETIME between TO_DATE(''" & from_date_string & " 00:00:00'',''dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') and TO_DATE(''" & to_date_string & " 23:59:59 '',''dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') ), " & _
'"union_queries as (select * from untagged_affiliates union select * from untagged_unv_subs ) select uq.*, case when (L.LOCATION_NAME = ''Bangalore'') then ''BLR'' when (L.LOCATION_NAME = ''Beijing'' or L.LOCATION_NAME = ''Singapore'') then ''Asia'' when (L.LOCATION_NAME = ''Gdansk'' or L.LOCATION_NAME = ''Nicosia'') then ''EMEA'' else ''Other'' end as REGION, C.COUNTRYDESC, u.USERID, u.username as ANALYST " & _
'"from union_queries uq left join oa.organizations o on uq.entityid = o.orgid left join admin.USERS U on UQ.ANALYST = U.USERID inner join admin.USERSUSERGROUPS ug on u.userid = ug.userid and ug.groupcode in (1,2,4,29,30,31,34,42,43,45,46,55,56) left join DOMAINS.COUNTRYCODES C on coalesce(o.org_country_of_domicile,o.org_country_of_incorporation) = C.COUNTRYCODE left join domains.TR_LOCATIONS l on u.PRIMARYLOCATION = l.LOCATION_ID')"
'recset.Open SQL_String, con
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Untagged").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recset
```

From this, I'm getting the following error:
[image]

As such, I suppose that I can't make a single query where two tables have columns with the same name and them use them for a UNION. But how do I go about to unite the tables if I can't assign the column ANALYST the same name on both?

Comment: You have `ife.analystuserid as ANALYST` and `u.username as ANALYST`. Just remove the `As Analyst` from the first `analystuserid`.

Comment: In your query, uq.* already has ANALYST column coming from the cte untagged_affiliates and untagged_unv_subs and you are also naming the column u.username as ANALYST. That is the issue.